# C++ - read part of a binary file into a bitset

Tags: c++, file

I have a `C++` application where I need to read a portion of a binary file and put those bytes into a `std::bitset`.

I am able to read the correct portion of the binary file into a `std::string` object, but I don't want to go from `unsigned char->std::string->std::bitset` if I can avoid it.

**Is there a way to directly read a portion of the file into a bitset?**

So far I have the code (in this example, I'm starting at position 64, then reading 128 bytes into a `string`, and then initializing a `bitset`):

```
//Open the file
std::ifstream file (path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

//Move to the position to start reading
file.seekg(64); 

//Read 128 bytes of the file
std::vector<unsigned char> mDataBuffer;
mDataBuffer.resize( 128 ) ;
file.read( (char*)( &mDataBuffer[0]), 128 ) ;

//Read as string (I'm trying to avoid this)
std::string s_data( mDataBuffer.begin(), mDataBuffer.end()); 
std::bitset<1024> foo (s_data); //8 bits/byte x 128 bytes = 1024 bits

file.close()
```

Comment: Why use the `std::ios::ate` flag when you immediately seek to an absolute position? Also, using the `ate` flag for an input stream doesn't really make much sense as if you don't seek away from the end there's nothing to read.

Comment: It's a damn shame, but I can't find anything in the reference that would allow that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In the larger picture, this code is inside a loop where I do move around the file. That said, I grabbed `ios:ate` from an example somewhere so it very well could be used incorrectly (I'm not really sure how to use it).

Answer (score 0):

As I read the documentation of bit set<>, the string is expected to contain just '1' and '0's. So in your case, just iterate over all bits in your mDataBuffer and use set to set a bit in the bit set.

And of cause, you could stick with the `vector< unsigned char >` and pull the bits out, if you need them. That makes sense, if you just need to access a few bits.

Comment: I think he wanted to avoid the O(n_of_bits) operation here.

Comment: Sure, we all would like to avoid it, but the answer is: it's impossible :-)

Comment: Agreed, I would like to avoid it. But if it's impossible, then that's the answer. Given I'm not a expert at C++ in the least, I looked to SO for advice. :-)